# How to disable click trigger on thead when using jQuery Tablesorter 2.0 plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to have up and down arrow to manually trigger sorting event, but when I click the padding area in the thead, the sorting event also got triggered. If I forbid the column using `sorter: false` option, then the whole column will be disabled, and arrow won't be effective either. So how do I change to only trigger sorting event by arrow img?

Codes are more understandable as below shown, I have to open the columns I want to have sortable:

```
    $("#mainList").tablesorter( {
    headers: { 
        0: {
            sorter: false
        },
        // 1: { 
        //  sorter: false 
        // },
        // 2: {
        //  sorter: false
        // },
        3: {
            sorter: false
        }
    } 
} );
```

But if so, the click event will also be triggered on when I click on the padding area, not only the arrow:

```
    $("#sortTblByNameUp").click(function() {
    $("#mainList").trigger("sorton", [ [[2, 0]] ] ); 
    return false; 
}).hover(function(){
    $("#sortTblByProductCountUp").attr('src', '/imgserver/images/v2/up_gray.gif');
    $("#sortTblByNameDown, #sortTblByProductCountDown").attr('src', '/imgserver/images/v2/down_gray.gif');

    $(this).attr('src', '/imgserver/images/v2/up.gif');
});
```

Here is a working jsfiddle I think is much more understandable: http://jsfiddle.net/3aN8Q/6/  (I don't want to fire the sorting event when I click on the red area)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may `unbind` the click-listeners for the header:

```
$("#mainList").tablesorter( {
    headers: { 
        0: {
            sorter: false
        },
        3: {
            sorter: false
        }
    } 
} ).find('thead .header').unbind('click');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3aN8Q/9/

(in jQuery 1.7+ use [`off()`](http://api.jquery.com/off/))